# Sails.js 0.11 and passport: 'Missing Credentials' error

Tags: javascript, node.js, authentication, sails.js, passport.js

I've followed tutorial from this site: http://iliketomatoes.com/implement-passport-js-authentication-with-sails-js-0-10-2/

Signup form works correctly, everything is saved to my database (MongoDB) but when I want to log in, I've got `missing credentials` error:

```
{
  "message": "Missing credentials",
  "user": false
}
```

This is strange, I've cloned https://github.com/iliketomatoes/passport_with_sails , `sails lift` it and everything works fine. I've copied all api source files and configuration to my project. Only views are different but I'm sure that I'm using inputs with names: `email` and `password`. And still I have this error.

I was using MongoDB as a database, I've switched to local-disk (as in this repo) and still the same problem. I've changed versions of npm modules in `package.json` file to the one from the repo and still the same error. It is strange.

Also I have to mention that POST request contains `email` and `password` fields. I've double checked it.

Someone knows what can cause this problem?

EDIT:
My `login.ejs` view looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div id="content" class="col-sm-12 full">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="login-box">

        <div class="header">
          Login to JSCS Dashboard
        </div>


        <form class="form-horizontal login" action="/login" method="POST">

          <fieldset class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="controls row">
                <div class="input-group col-sm-12">
                  <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="E-mail"/>
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
              <div class="controls row">
                <div class="input-group col-sm-12">
                  <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password"/>
                  <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i></span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="row">


              <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary col-xs-12">

            </div>

          </fieldset>

        </form>

        <a class="pull-left" href="auth-layout.ejs#">Forgot Password?</a>

        <div class="clearfix"></div>

      </div>
    </div><!--/row-->

  </div>



</div><!--/row-->
```

It is saved in `Auth` subfolder but displayed correctly. Signup form looks very similar to it and it works.

Comment: Can you check in your passport.js configuration file that you specified the username and password fields using the usernameField and passwordField properties?

Comment: yes, its using. I've also tried to rename `email` into `username` and get rid of this custom properties without success. Its strange because, like i said, I've copied all `api` folder files into my project from tutorial repository. Running tutorial repostory is fine, all works as expected. But when i switch to my project, i see above error. 

If you visit tutorial repository ` api` folder. You will see the same code as in my project :)

Comment: I dont think the problem is within the api folder. My guess is that it has something to do with the view. Can you update your question with the view syntax?

Comment: I've added `login.ejs` syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so the problem was that another service was interfering with AuthController. Anyway thanks for help

Answer (score 2):

replace this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal login" action="/login" method="POST">.
```

with this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal login" action="/auth/local" method="POST">
```

also you might want to consider to use this tutorial instead: https://www.bearfruit.org/2014/07/21/tutorial-easy-authentication-for-sails-js-apps/

Its alot easier to implement It with that tutorial as it does most of the stuff you did automaticly.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this another tutorial. I've found a problem. It was another service using passport interfering with auth :/